# python request remote web server via CLI through a ssh tunnel?

Tags: python, portforwarding, socks, ssh-tunnel

I installed a web server on a remote machine that can be only access through a ssh tunnel. Therefore, I have run with putty a ssh tunnel by specifying a port forwarding (in my case 8159). I have also configured the socks proxy on my browser to access to my remote webserver. Futhermore, with a curl command I can get the webpages if I add the following option --sock5-hostname localhost:8159.

Now, I would like to use python to request those webpages by passing through the ssh tunnel that I have configured with putty. I tried pysocks and proxy environment variables in my python code but it did not work. I would like to know if you have an idea to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.